# Spring Data. Как создать been из интерфейса?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Хочу научиться использовать Spring Data без Spring Boot.

Следуя инструкциям вот этой [записи](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwM7A4TwU3M) создаю интерфейс-репозиторий наследуемый от **CrudRepository**. В конфигурации ставлю аннотацию **@EnableJpaRepositories**. Создаю класс с main(), реализую в нем логику, и подымаю контекст с помощью **AnnotationConfigApplicationContext**.

Но при запуске программы контекст не находит нужные **Bean**.
Как создать нужный **Bean** репозитория **без Spring Boot**?

**Main:**

```
public class TestMain {

@Resource(name = "authorService")
private AuthorService authorService;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class,
            ServiceConfig.class);

    TestMain main = (TestMain) ctx.getBean("testMain");
    main.test();

    ctx.close();
}

private void test() {
    Author a = authorService.getAuthor(42L);
    System.out.println("Hi, i'm " + a.getName());
}
```

Репозиторий:

```
@Component
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {
}
```

Сервис:

```
@Component
public class AuthorService {
    @Autowired
    private AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    public Author getAuthor(Long id) {
        Optional<Author> author = authorRepository.findById(id);
        return author.get();
    }
}
```

JavaConfig:

```
@Configuration
@Import(RepositoryConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(value ="by.net.iozhukov.grizzly.application")
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public TestMain testMain() {
        return new TestMain();
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(OrmConfig.class)
public class RepositoryConfig {
}
```

Нижнее исключение:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'by.net.iozhukov.application.repository.impl.AuthorRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: У класса ServiceConfig есть аннотация @ComponentScan?

Comment: Добавь описание ошибки, которая падает, и класс `AppConfig`.

Comment: Добавление @ComponentScan никак не изменило картину.

Comment: А если в TestMain над AuthorService Autowired поставить?

Comment: Установка @Autowired не помогла, и это бы ничего не изменило. Т.к. более ранний бин в цепочке зависемостей не может быть создан.